# SP 2010 Related Item View link not using default display form

Tags: hyperlink

I'm working with a parent/child list page that I've added a "Related Item View" of the child list at the bottom of the page. This works great and shows all the child items.

I also have customized my New, Edit, and Display forms for the child list and made the new forms default. They work well, except on the page where I've added the Related Item View of the child list

On this page, when I look at it rended in a browser, each child item in this list is a link. The problem is that when I click on that link, the display form that pops up is not my new default display form, but the OOTB display form.

I can't figure out why this is happening or if there is a way to fix it.